# t-sql select based on preference

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table named `Table1` has below columns:

1. MessageId
2. Message
3. State
4. DateTimeStamp

The State can have the following values: `routing`, `delivered`, `rejected`

A record gets inserted when the message is first being routed.
A record then gets inserted when the message is being either delivered or rejected.

What I want to select is,

1. if a message has two records  with states `delivered` and `routing` then choose the record having state `delivered`.
2. if a message has two records  with states `rejected` and `routing` then choose the record having state `rejected`.
3. if a message has only one record with state `routing` then select it as is.

It is sort of a preference based select. Any help will be appreciated.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Table1;

CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
MessageId INT NOT NULL,
[Message] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
[State] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
DateTimeStamp DATETIME --DEFAULT(GETDATE())
);

INSERT #Table1 (MessageId, Message, State, DateTimeStamp) VALUES 
(1, 'xxx', 'routing', getdate()), 
(2, 'xxx', 'delivered', dateadd(hh,1,getdate())),
(3, 'yyy', 'routing', dateadd(hh,2,getdate())), 
(4, 'yyy', 'rejected', dateadd(hh,3,getdate())),
(5, 'aaa', 'routing', dateadd(hh,4,getdate())), 
(6, 'zzz', 'routing', dateadd(hh,5,getdate())), 
(7, 'zzz', 'unknown', dateadd(hh,6,getdate()))

--=========================================================
MessageId   Message State        DateTimeStamp
    1         xxx   routing     2017-07-14 09:07:16.840
    2         xxx   delivered   2017-07-14 10:07:16.840
    3         yyy   routing     2017-07-14 11:07:16.840
    4         yyy   rejected    2017-07-14 12:07:16.840
    5         aaa   routing     2017-07-14 13:07:16.840
    6         zzz   routing     2017-07-14 14:07:16.840
    7         zzz   unknown     2017-07-14 15:07:16.840

--QUERY

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
t1.MessageId,
t1.[Message],
t1.[State],
t1.DateTimeStamp FROM 
#Table1 t1 ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Message ORDER BY IIF(t1.[State] = 'routing', 1, 0))

--RESULTSET

MessageId   Message    State    DateTimeStamp
5            aaa    routing     2017-07-14 13:04:58.997
2            xxx    delivered   2017-07-14 10:04:58.997
4            yyy    rejected    2017-07-14 12:04:58.997
7            zzz    unknown     2017-07-14 15:04:58.997

--EXPECTED RESULTSET WITH DATETIMESTAMP DESC

MessageId   Message    State    DateTimeStamp
7            zzz    unknown     2017-07-14 15:04:58.997
5            aaa    routing     2017-07-14 13:04:58.997
4            yyy    rejected    2017-07-14 12:04:58.997
2            xxx    delivered   2017-07-14 10:04:58.997
```

I can only achieve the expected resultset if I put the resultset in the temp table and select from it and order by datetimestamp desc. Would be nice if there was a way to do without going through another layer of inserts and selects

Comment: Have you tried any query so far which you can post in your question?

Comment: `A record gets inserted when the message is first being routed. A record then gets inserted when the message is being either delivered or rejected.`. What is common between these two records? Is it `MessageId` or `Message`?

Comment: Message is common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a perfect situation for using "TOP N WITH TIES"...

Check the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Table1;

CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
    MessageId INT NOT NULL,
    [Message] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [State] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    DateTimeStamp DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())
    );

INSERT #Table1 (MessageId, Message, State) VALUES 
    (1, 'xxx', 'routing'), (1, 'yyy', 'delivered'),
    (2, 'xxx', 'routing'), (2, 'yyy', 'rejected'),
    (3, 'xxx', 'routing'), 
    (4, 'xxx', 'routing'), (4, 'yyy', 'delivered')

--=========================================================

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
    t1.MessageId,
    t1.[Message],
    t1.[State],
    t1.DateTimeStamp
FROM 
    #Table1 t1
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.MessageId ORDER BY IIF(t1.[State] = 'routing', 1, 0), t1.DateTimeStamp DESC);
```

Edit after revised OP:
Looking at the updat, it looks like the output is correct... You just want to change the final sort. I that's the case, I'd recommend sorting it in the display layer. That said, if the sort MUST be done by SQL Server, you can simply use the 1st query as a derived table and do the sort in the outer query. See below...

```
SELECT 
    m.MessageId,
    m.Message,
    m.State,
    m.DateTimeStamp
FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
            t1.MessageId,
            t1.[Message],
            t1.[State],
            t1.DateTimeStamp 
        FROM 
            #Table1 t1 
        ORDER BY 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Message ORDER BY IIF(t1.[State] = 'routing', 1, 0), t1.DateTimeStamp DESC)
        ) m
ORDER BY 
    m.DateTimeStamp DESC;
```

HTH,
Jason

Comment: Thank you. We are almost there! I have made minor edits to your post by correcting data values and added the resultset and the expected resultset to where I need to be.

Comment: If you'd like to add amended test data, please add it to your you original post. Editing my answer makes it look like I'm the one asking the question. Please feel free to copy/past from my post, but please do not  edit it.

Comment: Yikes. my bad, Jason. I was originally doing that but the stackoverflow allowed me only 5 mins to edit my comments. Whatever the case is, I will modify my original post. I am 99% close to what I am looking for based on the solution you provided.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm still new to posting on this forum and I'm still trying to figure out what's what around here. If you're able, try adding the updated test data & expected results as a new answer. If that doesn't work, re-edit my post and simply place it under my original response.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I just modified my original post with the code and expected result. If you can please have a look and advise. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jason!

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work for you. You require a group by clause:

```
select * from 
(select [Message],COUNT([message]) AS MessageCount
from Table1
group by [Message]) AS T
where MessageCount = 1
```

Comment: That didn't do it and I am not sure if I am able to explain it properly. Let me try again. If the message is either delivered or rejected then only that record should be displayed, otherwise it should display the record with "routing" state. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've updated your post. Please see if the conditions are now correct.

Comment: thanks for correcting the post. yes, the conditions appear to be correct now. Your solution above however is not exactly addresses that. I believe it can be handled using rank() over Partition but not quite sure just how.